# How can I use fake datacontext for Specflow tests

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, functional-testing, specflow

I am writing specflow tests and I would like to run from an in-memory database to get the tests to run faster and have more control over my data.

Currently:
Using the Unit Of Work lifetime for datacontext
http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2007/11/29/linq-to-sql-the-multi-tier-story/

Using a fake context set up similar to:
http://refactorthis.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/mock-faking-dbcontext-in-entity-framework-4-1-with-a-generic-repository/

How can I use this fake context with Specflow? I can't seem to access the current dbcontext singleton from Specflow, so I can't just set the fake datacontext there and have it affect the running tests.

Could I somehow tell my  website that I am testing in specflow and to use the fakecontext in that scenario? Should I use a button press or a url parameter or is there something else I can do?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use this fake context with Specflow? I can't seem to access the current dbcontext singleton from Specflow, so I can't just set the fake datacontext there and have it affect the running tests.

Since you haven't actually said what your error is, I'm going to make a wild guess that the `internal static class FakeContext` is declared in an assembly different to the one that your SpecFlow tests are declared. If this is the case then you need to add

```
[assembly:InternalsVisibleTo("MyApplication.SpecFlowTests")] //name of the test assembly
```

to the AssemblyInfo.cs of the Assembly that includes `FakeContext`.

Or alternatively declare the class as `public`.

> Could I somehow tell my website that I am testing in specflow and to use the fakecontext in that scenario? Should I use a button press or a url parameter or is there something else I can do?

You could tell the website that you are testing it, but if some malicious individual finds out the sequence to do that in production, then you will have problems.

Since you are talking about mocking your database and testing a website then I will assume that you are using ATDD (see last paragraph of [Development_style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development#Development_style)), then a better approach would be to automate the hosting of your website at the same time that you start your browser in an automated fashion (usually via Selenium). This way you can control how your website chooses its Database without exposing that functionality to the world at large.

Comment: I can see the assembly and access the static context, but the values I set in my acceptance tests project don't propagate to my running website(or vice versa).

Comment: I wasn't too concerned with someone finding out how to run it against the fake database(I definitely considered it), since they wouldn't be able to make any changes that persisted.

Comment: I'm attempting to run this in VS2010 - were you suggesting to start the ASP.NET development server in a specific way when started from the acceptance tests project?